# What is the difference between %lx and %ld when printing an address from pointer?

Tags: c

I have tried googling the first one for %lx, but I have no good results, BUT I have successfully searched up %ld which is just long int. Necessary for printing addresses I guess, but what is %lx for?

This is where I am confused:

```
int main()
{
    int value = 25;
    int *pointer = &value;
    printf("%ld\n", pointer);  // prints out the address of variable value( I hope)
    printf("0x%lx\n", pointer); // Completely confused here, is this perhaps address in hex?
}
```

Would be awesome if someone can clear this confusion I am having!

I have ran this code, and I have the results, but I am still not sure what the lx does..I have seriously tried googling this "%lx" in google, but no results explaining it.

Edit: if I use 'p' to print address then have I been wrong in thinking %ld prints address? Confused.

Comment: Try googling the manual page for `printf`.

Answer (score 32):

### They're both undefined behavior.

To print a pointer with printf, you should cast the pointer to `void *` and use `"%p"`.

### That being said:

We can talk about the difference between `"%ld"` and `"%lx"` when trying to print integers. `%ld` expects a variable of type `long int`, and `%lx` expects a variable of type `long unsigned int`.

More or less though, The difference between `x`, `o`, `d` and `u` are about how numbers are going to be printed.

- `x` prints an unsigned number in hexadecimal.
- `o` prints an unsigned number in octal.
- `u` prints an unsigned number in decimal.
- `d` prints a signed number in decimal.
- `i` prints a signed number in decimal.

We can then attach `l` to the format string for formats like `%lx` to specify that instead of an `int`, we're using a `long int` (That is, an `unsigned long int`, or `long int`).

There is a table at cppreference that has additional information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: I see...but what does %lx mean? Long x?

Comment: @Ray: Has the updated answer cleared up some of your confusion?

Comment: @Ray: `l` stands for "Long", `x` for "heXadecimal". `%lx` means to print an argument of type `unsigned long` in hexadecimal. (There is no format to print a signed argument in hexadecimal.)

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, depending on the platform, any one of the following may accidentally work on pointers: `%x`, `%lx` and `%llx`.  It depends on (a) how big the pointer is versus and (b) what is the size of `int`.

Comment: To elaborate a little on @Mark Lakata 's comment, using `%x`, `%lx`, or `%llx` on a pointer will express `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(long)`, or `sizeof(long long)` bytes of data in hexadecimal. On architectures where `sizeof(int *)` is larger than `sizeof(int)`, `%x` will express part of a pointer. Where `sizeof(int *)` is smaller than `sizeof(int)`, `%x` will express the pointer and whatever data follows the pointer in memory. Where `sizeof(int *)` and `sizeof(int)` are equal, `%x` will express just the pointer.

Comment: @Steve You're also assuming that the compiler will pass pointers and integers in the same manner to a function. __That doesn't need to be true__.

Comment: @sharth Good point. On a register rich architecture, pointers might be passed in pointer registers, and integers in integer registers. Additionally, if the size of a pointer and the size of the selected length of integer differ, the `varargs` part of `printf` will get confused, and any subsequent values passed in will be processed incorrectly. However, in typical implementations, it is *likely* to work if the pointer size matches the selected integer size – but don't count on it. That's why we have `%p`.

Comment: Is not a cast required? `printf("%p", (void *) &value);`?

Comment: @chux: Yes. And this is like the third time I've done an answer where I've forgotten this...

Comment: [Bully for you](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bully-for-you!-or-him-etc.)

Answer (score 2):

`%p` and `%lx` prints the address in hexadecimal while `%ld` prints it in decimal